# WooCommerce - Adding a review button on customer view order page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, review, orders

On my WooCommerce template, the "add review" feature display on single product page, like in this [**Website link**](http://peqen.com/product/handmade/ornamen-rumah/pencil-case-super-stylish/):

This seems difficult for my customers. I intend to move the button "Add a review" function at the bottom of the customer view Order page.

So when a customer see the order (whith "completed" status), then he could simply "click" on this new button and review will automatically be updated for this purchased product on his single product page.

I would like to customize my Woocommerce Template like this:

[image]

I add the new button **`beri testimoni`** on bottom of customer view order page, with this code:

```
<div class="reviews-form">
    <a href="#review_form" class="element-button element-colorbox"><?php _e('Add Review', 'makery'); ?></a>
</div>
<div class="site-popups hidden">
    <div id="review_form">
        <div class="site-popup large">
            <div class="site-form">
                <?php
                $commenter=wp_get_current_commenter();

                $comment_form=array(
                    'title_reply' => '',
                    'title_reply_to' => '',
                    'comment_notes_before' => '',
                    'comment_notes_after' => '',
                    'fields' => array(
                        'author' => '<div class="column fourcol static"><label for="author">'.__('Name', 'makery').'</label></div><div class="eightcol column static last"><div class="field-wrap"><input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author']).'" size="30" aria-required="true" /></div></div>',
                        'email' => '<div class="column fourcol static"><label for="email">'.__('Email', 'makery').'</label></div><div class="eightcol column static last"><div class="field-wrap"><input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_email']).'" size="30" aria-required="true" /></div></div>',
                    ),
                    'label_submit' => __('Kirim', 'makery'),
                    'name_submit' => 'submit',
                    'class_submit' => '',
                    'logged_in_as' => '',
                    'comment_field' => '',
                );

                if(get_option('woocommerce_enable_review_rating')=== 'yes'){
                    $comment_form['comment_field']='<div class="column fourcol static"><label for="rating">'.__('Rating', 'makery').'</label></div>
                    <div class="column eightcol static last"><div class="element-select"><span></span>
                    <select name="rating" id="rating">
                        <option value="">&ndash;</option>
                        <option value="5">'.__('Puas!', 'makery').'</option>
                        <option value="4">'.__('Keren, tapi...', 'makery').'</option>
                        <option value="3">'.__('Bagus', 'makery').'</option>
                        <option value="2">'.__('Lumayan, tapi...', 'makery').'</option>
                        <option value="1">'.__('Jelek!', 'makery').'</option>
                    </select></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';
                }

                $comment_form['comment_field'].= '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="6" aria-required="true" placeholder="'.__('Review', 'makery').'"></textarea>';
                comment_form(apply_filters('woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args', $comment_form));
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /popups -->
```

***Note:*** This code is the same as the code "add review " on the page single product.

But, this produce some errors and **is not working**...

What I am doing wrong? 
How could I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: The reviews are only for a single product pages and not for cart, checkout and thankyou pages… The first reason is that you can have many products on all of this pages. So to make it work, you will need to add this button for each item in your order. You have to think different. **So you can't have it at the bottom of the order** - NOT POSSIBLE

Comment: Hi, the screenshoot isn't from cart, but on buyer order page. And, the bottom have placed on the single buyer order page. i've place the buttom before. But, the function only redirect to purchased product page. For doing this, i used some code php.

Comment: I know (as I have corrected/clarified your question)… It's just the same thing for *(buyers)* customers order view page… as you can have many products (items) for one order, **this is NOT possible**. This is only possible for single product pages.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the above code into the functions.php file. It will create a review button right on your order history page: https://my-domain/my-account/orders

```
function custom_add_review_link_to_my_account( $actions, $order ) {
if ( ! $order || ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return $actions;
}

$order_id = $order->get_id();
$order_status = $order->get_status();
$reviewed = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_reviewed', true );

if ( $order_status === 'completed' && ! $reviewed ) {
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $product_id = 0;
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        break;
    }
    $product_url = get_permalink( $product_id );
    if ( $product_url ) {
        $actions['review'] = array(
            'url'  => $product_url . '#reviews',
            'name' => '★★★★★',
        );
    }
}

return $actions; } add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'custom_add_review_link_to_my_account', 10, 2 );
```